# Is there any method can print all member variable of a struct?

Tags: c++, stl

i have a series of struct, i want to add a show method for them.

please see the following code:

```
A {
  int a, b, c;
  void Show() {
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
  }
};

B {
  int a, b;
  void Show() {
    cout << a << " " << b  << endl;
  }
};
```

as you can see, i need to define a show function for each one, but i have a lot of struct.

is there any method i can use, like: `A a; Show(a)`, can do this in one definition?

Comment: Short answer, No.  One or more output and input function are generally required to be implemented.  Once C++ gets reflection you should have more options.

Comment: No you can't. And I suggest you overload the "output" operator `<<` so you can do e.g. `A a; /* Initialize members of a */ std::cout << a << '\n';`

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude says, you can define a function for `A` such as `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const A &a) { out << a.a << " " << a.b << " " << a.c; return out; }`.

Comment: @fanfly Except the function should use `out` instead of `std::cout`... :) Also, since the operator returns the stream, one could do `return out << ...;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes you are right; I mistyped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't such a mechanism in the standard library. For types such as your `A` and `B`, you should be able to use [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)